# Getting Issue In Gracenote TMSAPI

Tags: php

Hello there I want to fetch channel listing  By Reffering below link:

http://developer.tmsapi.com/docs/data_v1_1/lineups/Lineup_channel_listing

But I can't Access My Line Up ID  With My Api Key.

http://data.tmsapi.com/v1.1/lineups/USA-NY55899-X/channels?api_key=myapi_key

I got 'Developer Inactive' Or '403 Access Forbidden(proxy)' OR 'Not Authorized' Error.

Can Somebody tell me why these errors occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can Somebody tell me why these errors occurs?

That could be 2 things:

- OR your API key is invalid
- OR you do not have enough rights with that API key to access that endpoint.

I assume you are using a real API key instead of "myapi_key" or "1234567890" like the docs say - these are examples and should be replaced by the API key you received when you signed up as developer to the platform.

Also - USA-NY55899-X might also be an example from the docs - you might need to get an actual lineupId by first looking up `/lineups` first - like the docs tell you.

There's no other way to answer your question without more information or code I'm afraid.